# can't make cross browser AJAX request to work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am doing a simple ajax request to another domain like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.clik').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://sub.mydomain.com/test.php",
              crossDomain: true,
              dataType:"jsonp",
              success: function(data) {

                    $('p.txt').html(data['no']);

              }

        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p class="clik">Halleluja</p>
<p class="txt"></p>
```

this is the test.php page on sub.mydomain.com

```
<?
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mydomain.com');
// Begin Session
require_once('cl.session.php');
$session = new Session();
$session->start_session('test', false);

// Access Database
require_once('cl.database.php');
$login_db = new Database('user', 'pass', 'accounts', 'test');
$login_pdo = $login_db->PDO;

include "fn.check_login.php";
if(checkLogin($login_pdo) == true) {

    // We start out by checking if the request has been made using AJAX
    if (is_ajax()) {

        echo "this is working";

    } else {

        echo "this is not working!";

    }

} else {
   echo 'You are not authorized to access this page, please login. <br/>';
}

// Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {

    // BOOLEAN return if AJAX
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';

}
?>
```

It returns a semantic issue.

Also if I simply echo some basic text:

```
<?
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

it still returns a semantic issue.

could somebody tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Not an answer but Short tags for php aren't recommended. Always open PHP tags as `<?php`

Comment: My Apache server is set to support it, but I'll take your advice.

Comment: Well, for a start, JSONP requests can't be `POST` (only `GET`). But I tend to assume jQuery is ignoring the invalid `type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for a start, JSONP requests can't be `POST` (only `GET`). But I tend to assume jQuery is ignoring the invalid `type`. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) is *intrinsically* a `GET`.

Your response to it is invalid. You've told jQuery you're expecting the server to provide a JSONP response. but your responses aren't JSONP.

A [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) response would look something like this:

```
callback({
   "property": "value",
   "anotherProperty": 42
})
```

...where the name of the callback (`callback` in the above) is taken from the query string of the request. So for instance, if the request were `http://sub.mydomain.com/test.php?callback=foo`, the response would use `foo` for the name of the callback:

```
foo({
   "property": "value",
   "anotherProperty": 42
})
```

jQuery will add the `callback=` query string parameter to the request for you automatically, and generate the corresponding function for you, which in turn calls the `ajax` success handler with the data passed into it.

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted: Read the link about JSONP, and read the [$.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) with regard to how it does JSONP. You don't specify `callback` in your URL explicitly. As I said above, jQuery will supply that (and the function) for you. Your server-side code just needs to use the `callback` query string parameter and use that as the name of the function. It'll have some long, weird name (because jQuery auto-generates them and tries to avoid conflicts).

Comment: Sorry sir.. I misunderstood you answer.. Thanks for your time.. Learned a lot from that..

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted: Glad that helped! Best,

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use the [jquery postMessage plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/postmessage) (or similar if there is one). Long time since I tried it but check if you load the script from the server you wish to call (think I tried that and failed in the past but hey - its worth a bash - report back if it does).